# Cannot uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 18 after forcefully stopping setup midway

Tags: uninstall, sql-server, ssms

I installed SQL Server 2017. It installed fine. I connected and turned it on (the server). Worked fine.
Then I downloaded the SSMS 18 setup. When I started the SSMS setup exe, it progressed to half the bar, and then stopped further. I waited quite long, but then gave up. I went to the Task Manager and killed the SQL Server Management Studio task. Afterwards, whenever I tried to complete the SSMS installation, it simply displayed the error : "Setup blocked".

[image: SSMS Uninstall error]

The same happens when I try to uninstall the SSMS now. So, I decided to manually remove the program from my PC. I uninstalled all the components of SQL Server 2017 from the Control Panel. Deleted all remaining files in C:\Program Files.
Even after this, I still couldn't uninstall SSMS 18. Even if I delete the SQL Server Management Studio 18 folder from C:\Program Files, I still receive the same error, and my control panel continues to show SSMS as installed on my computer, yet it doesn't show up in my Start Menu.

[image: Installed Programs in Control Panel]

Now, I need way to remove the SSMS 18 from my PC completely. I have not been able to find a solution from Google searches on the Web. Most sources explain uninstallation the regular way.

Answer (score 5):

I followed some steps from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37483594-ssms-18-0-ga-can-t-be-installed) which worked for me in similar situation:

1. Uninstalled SSMS 17.
2. Deleted "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18"
3. Deleted "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"
4. Uninstalled SSMS 18
5. Restarted
6. Reinstalled
7. Though install was success, it did not start, throwed an error: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect."
8. Started over from step 2. After second time installing it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with SSMS release 18.9.1. I had accidentally ended the installation midway through, and after trying to reinstall SSMS, it was stuck "loading packages". It also was showing up as an installed program, but it would not let me uninstall because it would still "load packages".

Similar to Endre Nyirő, I was able to fix the issue by:

- Deleting C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18,
- Backing up my registry and then deleting HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Uninstalling SSMS

You could use the command prompt to delete the registry key but I felt more comfortable with the application. For the application, you can hit WIN+r and type "regedit.exe". Just right click the SSMS folder listed above and click delete.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use Windows System Restore (if it is enabled). Select a time before you tried to install SSMS, then restore your system.